# Arbitrarily large $n$ divides $F_n$

Tags: integer-sequences, divisors-multiples

Is it true that there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with arbitrarily many prime factors such that $n$ divides $F_n$, where $F_n$ represents the n-th **Fibonacci number**?

Comment: To respond to the original version which didn't ask for infinitely many prime factors, $F_{5(2n+1)} = 5 (5 F_{2n+1}^5 - 5 F_{2n+1}^3 + F_{2n+1})$ so we can show inductively that $5^k | F_{5^k}$.

Comment: That's the reason I changed the question, as I realized on the spot the many ways to answer that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that (see [here](http://oeis.org/A023172)):

- If $a$ and $b$ are in your sequence, then so is $\text{lcm}(a,b)$;
- If $n$ is in the sequence, then so is $F_n$.

Now take any $n>12$ that belongs to the sequence, then $a_1=\text{lcm}(n,F_n)$, $a_2=\text{lcm}(n,F_n,F_{F_n})$, and so on. Each of $n$, $F_n$, $F_{F_n}$, ... belongs to the sequence by the second fact. Their successive least common multiples do as well by the first fact. Moreover, one has $\omega(a_k) \geq k-1+\omega(n)$ by [the theorem of Carmichael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_theorem), which answers your question affirmatively.

A more challenging version I didn't think about yet could be: for which $n \in \mathbb N$ is there an $N$ in the sequence such that $\omega(N)=n$?

Comment: Just for the record, using the results from an upcoming work of mine plus some conjectures about primes in shifted multiply exponential sequences, I can answer the more challenging question affirmatively too.

Comment: Here is the "upcoming work": http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.2489